# Is it possible to test a motherboard with AA batteries?

Tags: motherboard

I want to test my motherboard, so how do I run it with AA batteries?

In the 16-pin connector, I tried connecting 8 AA batteries to the +12V and GND and pressing the power button, but the fans didn't spin.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few factors here, and many of them point at the possibility of damaging your motherboard if you arn't sure what you're doing. You don't seem to, and this is a bad idea. You *shouldn't* be trying to boot a PC off a jerryrigged power supply without a good idea of what you're doing.

This is kinda anecdotal but I do suspect you might need some of the other  pins on the 24 pin out active - I do believe that the power ok connector might be important, and I've had my power supply shut down and my PC give an error after shorting 12v. That leads me to suspect its not enough to 'just' supply 12v. Stuff like standby also runs at 5v all the time.

I do know for certain that the *processor* on many boards has its own power supply connector and you need to power that too. Even with a proper, to spec modern ATX power supply, your system may not boot without power to the processor. I do believe its a pair of 12v leads and 2 grounds, and you need at least as much power there as the CPU requires. One can do a quick bit of math with some assumptions to work out how much you *could* need.

Lets assume you have a 15w CPU with 12v fed into it. Your required current to power it, assuming no losses is 1.25A. A quick google suggests you can get about 0.8A out of an [AA battery without issue](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/maximum-aa-battery-current-draw/#:%7E:text=The%20Energizer%20specifications%20for%20AA,power%20your%20regulator%20can%20provide.). While in theory you could use 2 or more sets in parallel, you're typically going to need more.

My NUC (while low powered) needs roughly 2.5A or so (30W) power with a 3W TDP processor. This would mean roughly 4 sets of 8 AA batteries in parallel for something that has 1/5th the power of a typical laptop CPU, let alone PC CPUs.

Typical ATX power supplies start at maybe 100w with the smallest I've seen being 80w. I'd recommend reading through and understanding the ATX power supply design guide to get an idea of what the *real* requirements are. It isn't simply a matter of supplying voltage.

Also unless its a ATX 12Vo board, you're going to need the *other* voltages for stuff around the motherboard.

Frankly - buying the cheapest PSU you can find for testing is going to save you time, energy (electrical and human) and batteries.

Answer (score 2):

Even a small motherboard with a fan will quickly drain an AA battery below 1.1 Volts (dead for all practical purposes).

Remember that batteries in series are limited to the current and resulting voltage of one battery.

So I am fairly sure that is the limit you hit.

Try D cells if you really need to do this.

Your local electronics store will have an inexpensive 12 to 14 DC power supply with good regulation and with whatever other voltages your motherboard needs. This is a much better solution. I have a couple of these in my workshop.

Get a supply that delivers a couple of amps or more regulated.

It would hook up the same way as batteries but do look up hardware specifications.

Comment: What pins do I have to connect?

Comment: Just look at your motherboard hardware specifications for the pinouts.

Answer (score 2):

That is not going to work for ***many*** reasons.  If you want to test a motherboard, connect it to a properly rated power supply.

While 8 1.5v AA batteries (in series) does make 12v, batteries do *not* have the amperage to power a motherboard.  Not to mention, you arent providing the 5v rail, or oven the 3.3v rail power, which the motherboard might expect to be present.  If there isnt enough amperage or voltage, many motherboard will assume there is a power supply problem and not turn on.

Comment: What is the current to power a mobo, and why will it assume a power supply problem if I just provide 12v?

Comment: @ssr215 How much power?  That will depend on your motherboard and the components attached to it.  Why would it assume a problem?  Not all the power rails are connected.

Comment: 12v at what wattage and what amperage? If this could be done don’t you think there would be tons of articles online pointing to it being doable?

Comment: Will it turn on when stripping and connecting a 12v 1.5a power adapter to the mobo?